# Print Powerpoint Slide from Python

Tags: python, powerpoint, win32com

I'm trying to print out a slide from Powerpoint. I've accessed the slide using the following code:

```
from win32com import client
powerpoint = client.Dispatch("Powerpoint.Application")
presentation = powerpoint.presentations.Open(filepath)
slide = presentation.Slides[10]
print(slide.name)  # Just to check I have in fact got the slide
```

When printing Word docs I can just call `PrintOut()` on the document but it doesn't seem to work for Powerpoint.

Does anyone have any solutions?

```
presentation.PrintOut()
```

prints the entire presentation, but I just want a specific slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out I can specify a range using:

```
presentation.PrintOut(From=1, To=1)
```

And I can iterate the slides to match the name using a loop:

```
count = 1
for slide in presentation.Slides:
    if slide.name == "Slide1":
        presentation.PrintOut(From=count, To=count)
        break
    count += 1
```